# Supervisor on raspberry pi stops logging to log file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, supervisord

I have a temperature sensor connected to my rpi with a python script running.  I can start the python script from the cli and it will run outputting the temps until I stop it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def sensor():
    for i in os.listdir('/sys/bus/w1/devices'):
        if i != 'w1_bus_master1':
            ds18b20 = i
return ds18b20

def read(ds18b20):
    location = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/' + ds18b20 + '/w1_slave'
    tfile = open(location)
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
    celsius = temperature / 1000
    farenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
    return celsius, farenheit

def loop(ds18b20):
    while True:
        if read(ds18b20) != None:
            print "Current temperature : %0.3f C" % read(ds18b20)[0]
            print "Current temperature : %0.3f F" % read(ds18b20)[1]

def kill():
    quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        serialNum = sensor()
        loop(serialNum)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        kill()
```

I have configured supervisor with a temp config to run.  It starts fine on reboot and starts to output the temps in the file but eventually stops logging.  There aren't any errors that I can tell.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:whelping-box-temp]
command=python /home/pi/workspace/my-donutz/whelping-box-temp-sensor.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/whelping-box-temp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/whelping-box-temp.out.log
```

I am assuming that I don't want to keep logging to a file on the rpi because it would eventually run out of space and degrade over time.

```
Current temperature : 24.750 C
Current temperature : 76.662 F
Current temperature : 24.750 C
Current temperature : 76.662 F
Current temperature : 24.750 C
Current temperature : 76.662 F
Current temperature : 24.750 C
Current temperature : 76.550 F
Current temperature : 24.812 C
Current temperature : 76.662 F
Current temperature : 24.812 C
Current temperature : 76.662 F
Current temp
```

That last line is not a typo it is where the output seems to be stopping.  If I delete the log file and reboot it will do the same thing next time around.

Is there another way that I should be configuring supervisor on the rpi or even using supervisor at all?  Why does it stop logging after a short while?  Eventually I'll have the rpi do something else when the temp is at a certain spot but I would like to be able to log in and see some sort of history of what has been going on.  What is the correct way to do that on a rpi?

Comment: How big is the logfile when logging stops?  `supervisord` has a default limit of 50MB for a logfile.  You can change that size, and you can also arrange for logfiles to be rotated after they reach that size.  See the `..._logfile_maxbytes` and `..._logfile_backups` configuration options for details.